# Bibtex and BST file: sorting references by order of appearence first AND date second

Tags: cross-referencing, sorting

I am using bibtex4word to sort my references within my word documents. I've got a bib file created by Jabref to pick up my references.

Currently, I use the style "IEEEtran" to sort my references. This style is perfect for me since it sorts by order of appearance within the text. However, for multiple consecutive citations, I would like to further order by date. IEEEtran is not doing this. For instance if I have :
"The reference [1] is better than these [2-4]."

I want my reference list to be :
[1] A. aaa and B. bbb, blablabla, 2012
[2] A. aaa and B. bbb, blablabla, 1980
[3] A. aaa and B. bbb, blablabla, 2000
[4] A. aaa and B. bbb, blablabla, 2018

In other word, I want the block [2-4] to be automatically ordered by date.

I tried to create a new .BST file to write my own ordering but I fail to do what I want. All I can do is sorting by date only or by appearence only...

Could someone help me on this? It seems difficult to understand these BST files...

Thanks.

Comment: if you order by first appearance then bibtex does not sort at all as that is just the order the entries are seen, so you can't specify a second sort key (and also normally a second sort key is only used if the primary sort keys are equal which can not be the case here)

Comment: Try to use ieeetrans style instead.

Comment: I understand the natural order of entries is the default order but is it possible to impose this order by coding it and then order by date as second sort key?